# How to quickly exit radare2 from debug mode?

Tags: radare2

Normally in CLI apps you can use `Ctrl + c` / `Ctrl + d` to terminate/exit, but they don't seem to do anything in `r2` - at least not in debugger's `v` (visual) mode, which is how I use it. To exit, I press `q`, then type "exit", and have to press `y` twice to confirm quitting and killing the process, which is quite tedious.

Is it possible to terminate a visual debugging session and exit `r2` with a single key combination ?